# Parameter is no valid when convert byte to image c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, window, memorystream

I have done inserting image into database and the datatype is image, but when I want to retrieve it, it is very difficult and error will show Parameter is not valid.

```
public void RetrieveImage()
  {
   var con = new SqlConnection(Connection.CATAS_LOCAL());
   string SQL = "Select Name,Image from dbo.[TestImage] where Name = 'Test1'";
   var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
   con.Open();
   SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   Reader.Read();
   if (Reader.HasRows)
      {
       txtAddStaffNric.Text = Reader[0].ToString();
       byte[] img = (byte[])(Reader[1]);
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
       pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);  ** error show at this line
      }
  con.Close();
  }
```

Comment: The image datatype has been deprecated since 2005. You should instead use the varbinary(max) datatype. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: You should start your debugging by verifying if byte array you've started with is identical to one you've read from DB.

Comment: FWIW, image data type is deprecated. Try to avoid it if possible, use varbinary(max).
Also, Make sure you are writing the bytes correctly and that it is of supported format.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've use the varbinary(max) datatype. My problem solved. Sorry for late reply.